# Pass String or Employee object as parameter

Tags: java, dao

I have a method which will called from ManagedBean as follows

```
getemployeeService().findEmployees(qData);
```

`qData` is nothing but a class for passing parameters for lazyload `load` method.

```
EmployeeQueryData qData = new EmployeeQueryData(start, end, sortField, order, filters);
```

I would like to pass one for parameter to `findEmployees` method in DAO class for getting employees based on `deptNo`.

My doubt is should I pass another parameter like

```
getemployeeService().findEmployees(qData, String deptNo);
```

or pass Employees class as

```
getemployeeService().findEmployees(qData, Employees emp);
```

and in DAO I invoke `deptNo` as
`emp.getDeptNo`

What is the best approach and practice? Any suggestions and insight are highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that passing department makes more sense. Because when we say DAO layer we look only in the perspective that is has to deal with data. We should include emp.getDeptNo() in business logic tier.

But talking about extensibility, if future you may want to send some other params say dept,DOJ and so on. So in that case you can create another class say Criteria and place params field in that class and pass Object of this class to find() method.

Comment: Introducing different Criteria class because, there could be the case that where you want to club parameters from different classes like, Employee.DOJ, Employee.deptNo, HR.noFoLeaves etc. In that case passing two 'Complete' Objects i.e. HR and Employee popuylate Criteria Object adn pass it.

Comment: Vallabh, I already have Entity class for Employees, so do I need to have another class called Criteria? I could use same Entity class and pass Object of Entity class?

Comment: See my above comment. What if your find criteria is depending on 4-5 fields from 2-3 different classes.? In that case you have to pass 2-3 Entity class objects.?

Comment: I got your point, yes you are right. I would like to know in which package do I keep Criteria class if I have structure like Entity, Service, DAO, ManagedBean etc? Besides any documentation or examples for creating Criteria class? Thanks

Comment: I guess, criteria will always serve as Bean itself. (Fields and getters and setters that's all.) So, I think it will go in ManagedBeans.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches have pros and cons, however you should consider how likely the business requirement for your program will change.

For example, if in the future there's a change in requirement saying 'we should locate employee not just by his/her depno, but also employeeId', then the second approach will make it easier for you to implement the change. With the first approach you have to change every single invocation of the findEmployees method

Comment: gerrytan Thanks. Could you kindly provide a little more clarification for **With the first approach you have to change every single invocation of the findEmployees method**?

Comment: For example, if your searching criteria changes, you have to change everywhere you called findEmployees(qData, deptNo) into findEmployees(qData, deptNo, empoyeeId), whereas with the second approach -- assuming employeeId is just a field of the Employee class, you only need to change to implementation of findEmployee method